# Is there a more performant way to add an element to an array in a sorted position?

Tags: ruby

This method is just taking an element and inserting it in an ordered position in an already ordered array.

```
@ary = [9,7,3,1]
insert_in_order(5)
@ary = [9,7,5,3,1]
```

I've already determined that this is faster than just pushing the value on the array and running a sort! on it later.  But it seems like this is taking way more steps than it should.  Is there a more performant and more efficient way to do this?

```
def insert_in_order val
    @val = val
    @ary.each_with_index{|v,i| 
        if @val > v
            @found_index = i 
            break
        end
        }
    @found_index ? @ary.insert(@found_index, @val) : @ary.push(@val)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a binary search and find the index to which this element belongs and then insert at that index. Finding the index would take O(log(n)) and works only if the current list is guaranteed to be sorted

Answer (score 3):

Even with a binary search, as @Adithya Surampudi suggested, this will be quite slow. Since the elements of an array by definition are located in contiguous memory positions, inserting into an array at the *i* th last position will require *i* elements to be moved one position to the right in order to make room for the new element. You might want to consider a different data structure, such as a red-black tree (or a regular binary search tree if you're feeling lucky).

Comment: Are there any gems for search tree structures?

Comment: @Klaus: There should be, as search trees are included in the standard libraries of many languages, but as I don't program in Ruby, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

It's not more performant than what you have now, but I think it reads well, which IMHO is more important than performance until you know conclusively you have a bottleneck in your app:

```
>> ary = [9,7,3,1] #=> [9, 7, 3, 1]
>> val = 5 #=> 5
>> bigger, smaller = ary.partition{|x| x >= val} #=> [[9, 7], [3, 1]]
>> [*bigger, val, *smaller] #=> [9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

Comment: +1 for "more important than performance until...".  And if performance does matter, then a different data structure is in order.